# Variaton of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a particular solution to the differential equation
$-6 y'' +  y' +  y =  t^2  -  t  - 5 e^{-4 t} $.

This is my work so far.

[image]

I know I should be setting things to match up with the right hand side of the differential but I am stuck. I feel that my guess of at^2 + bt + c (e^(-4t)) is incorrect.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So, do you need just a guess, or use variation of parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form of the solution should be $a t^2 + b t + c + d e^{-4t}$.  The point being that ($0$ not being a root of the characteristic polynomial) to handle a polynomial of degree $2$ on the right side you need a polynomial of degree $2$ in the solution, potentially with all possible terms.  Since $-4$ is also not a root, to handle the the $e^{-4t}$ term you need a constant times $e^{-4t}$.  Note that those terms are added, not multiplied.

EDIT: By the way, this is "undetermined coefficients", not "variation of parameters". Variation of parameters would start with finding the basic solutions $e^{t/2}$ and $e^{-t/3}$ of the homogeneous system, and write the solution as
$u_1(t) e^{t/2} + u_2(t) e^{-t/3}$.